# Set mock location in request header

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** walmart pages for a project. I'm able to successfully grab the large JSON dataset which is provided in their webpage. However, I'm noticing the location is defaulted to California even though I'm in the Midwest. How can I create a mock location in my code? I read up on user agent but it looks like its "pretending" to be a chrome browser. I noticed when I implemented the chrome header, Walmart didn't consider me a robot and gave me a result based on my physical location. Thats a great first step but I'd like to change it to be different either via Latitude and Longitude or some other method.

I looked up HTTP header fields and I'm not sure I'm seeing a way to set it. I may also be looking at this the wrong way since I'm newer to scraping.

main.py

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parseWalmartProductPage(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36',
    }   
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    # parse the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    # parse the script tag used to lazy load the page
    scriptJSON = soup.find('script', attrs = {'id':'item'})
    
    # remove the script tags
    for script in soup(["script"]):
        script.extract()

    # get text from the script tag and return it as JSON
    jsonText = scriptJSON.get_text()
    return json.loads(jsonText)

print(parseWalmartProductPage("https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Whole-Milk-1-Gallon-128-Fl-Oz/10450114"))
```

Comment: You need to handle `location-data=94066:San Bruno:CA::0:0|21k,46y,1kf,1rc,46q,2nz,2b1,4bu,2er,1o1|2|7|1|1xun;16;0,1xtf;16;1,1xwj;16;2,1ygu;16;3,1xwq;16;4; DL=94066,,,ip,94066,,; nd_sess=0|1;` in the request `headers`

Comment: The first bits I understand, zip, city, and state. The rest I don't understand. Do you have documentation? I've been Googling for location-data and can't find anything

Comment: well, let me tell you it's all based on the server-side, where that parameter is holding a value which is actually stored within the server side. so if you changed it, you should be hardly decoded the meaning of each value and expect what's it in server side. but that's sound as a hack